# Firefox Javascript what does "can't convert to a primitive type" error mean?

Tags: javascript, firefox

this is my javascript test code:

```js
console.log( [] == 'a' );
```

when running in my firefox it gives this error:
"TypeError: can't convert [] to primitive type"

what does this mean? It does not seem to apply to every browser/browser version, or in my case, even a tab.

I have two chrome tabs open, if I try the code in one it gives an error, but in the other tab it works fine - making me very confused about the inconsistency.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp9KO.png) showing the errors

So what am I missing here, why the inconsistency on chrome? Any help appreciated!

(EDIT 1)
I've found that the error comes when adding/changing a bunch of prototypes onto the Array object, so how can I add prototypes without causing this error?

```js
{
  // if I omit the first line, the error does not occur
  Array.prototype.join = Array.prototype.concat;
  console.log( [] == 'a' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, this is a consequence of modifying the `Array` prototype. Specifically because the method `toString` is used during an equality check between an array and a primitive value.

Generally, when you use `==` where one operand is an object, javascript will try to convert the object to a primitive using [the steps outlined in the ECMAScript Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive). Parts 3 and 4 specifically:

> 3. If hint is "string", then let methodNames be «"toString", "valueOf"».
> 4. Else, Let methodNames be «"valueOf", "toString"».

As you can see, the `toString` method will be called as part of the attempt to convert the array to a primitive. The array `valueOf` method does not return a primitive by default, and **since you've overriden the `toString` method**, now it does not return a primitive either! Thus we move past step 5 and go on to 6 which says:

> 6. Throw a TypeError exception.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
const oldToString = Array.prototype.toString;
Array.prototype.toString = function() {
  console.log("Array toString method called!");
  return "[" + this.join(", ") + "]";
}

// No type error, because we converted to a primitive (in this
// case, a string) successfully.
console.log([1, 2, 3] == "[1, 2, 3]")

Array.prototype.toString = function() {
  return {};
}

// Type error, because we tried to convert to a primitive using
// toString, but we got an object back?!
console.log([1, 2, 3] == "[1, 2, 3]")
```

To be clear, this issue has *nothing to do with browser differences or Firefox specifically* but is instead a consequence of your modifications combined with the ECMAScript spec which *all* browsers follow.

Comment: thanks so much for answering! :)
I will read it thoroughly & have voted up but not enough rep to be publicly visible

(EDIT) Alright cool, appreciate all the information! Thanks again